# Is there a way to guarantee that my programming resfreshes when I enter it?

Tags: swift

I am having a problem with an app that I am programming in Swift. I would like it to display the splash view every time that I enter the app. However, when I press the home key to and then reload the app, it brings me straight to the view which I was displaying when I pressed the home button. I certainly don’t want this. I want the app to refresh every time I loard it.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW23 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this by creating a custom view controller say `SplashViewController` that only has an image view inside that shows the launch image.
in your `AppDelegate` head to the method `applicationWillEnterForeground` present this viewController in modal mode and in the `viewDidAppear` inside the `SplashViewController` use `NSTimer` or `GDC` to wait like whatever seconds then call `dismissViewController(animated:, completion:)` method from that controller.

```
let seconds = 4.0
let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)  // nanoseconds per seconds
var dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

   self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)

})
```